# Java Update JLabel With Database Output

Tags: java, database, jdbc, io, jlabel

so what I am trying to do is update a JLabel that is going to represent the number of files that are stored in my database.

I will use JDBC to communicate my Java application with my database (Oracle) and pass a SQL statement to my database to return output in this case it will be: `SELECT COUNT(File_ID) FROM Files;` which would give an output of say 50.

So now I would like to update my Jlabel I have to display the output, in this case it would read 50.

I know how to update a JTable with the results from a database like so:

```
try {
    String query = "SQL STATEMENT GOES HERE";
    pat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pat.executeQuery();
    myTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However I have never used output to update a Jlabel, if you have any suggestions or advice on how to achieve this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [`JLabel.setText(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Yes so my question is how can I update a String to store the output from my database?

Answer (score 0):

Just use  label.setText()

Edited: I didn't find an equivalent TextModel for jlabel (it exits for other components such as JTextField). Is it critical for you to go through a "Model" or is it good enough to setText("50")?

To extract the count do something like:

```
int count=0;
pat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT ..."); // complete as required
ResultSet rs=pat.executeQuery();// assuming it's "SELECT COUNT..."
if(rs.next())
  count=rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: I know how to simply set JLabel text. My question is a little more in depth than that. I need to figure out how to get output from my database (which comes in the form as a result set (using DBUtils)) changed into datatype String and then stored in a String variable. Then I can just use label.setText(String);

Comment: Your result set should hold a single column of type integer, so you'll have  "int count= rs.getInt(1)".  This should be easy to convert to text, e.g.  setText(""+count)

Comment: First let me just say thank you Pelit for taking time with this. I have made some changes and have comes up with this code: `try {
   String query = "SELECT COUNT(FILE_ID)FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1";
   pat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   rs = pat.executeQuery();
   if(rs.next()) output = rs.getInt(1);
   lblFiles.setText(String.valueOf(output));
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }` however I am still getting some NullPointerExceptions (it seems to be breaking on line: `lblFiles.setText(String.valueOf(output));`

Comment: Your code seems ok to me. My first suspicion is that lblFiles is null - could you check? Also could you please tell whether your 'output' is declared to be "int count" or "Integer count" (the latter could also be null)

Comment: lblFiles doesn't appear to be null it is containing just an empty string (waiting to be updated) and output was declared as `int output = 0;`

Comment: So sorry, I rechecked and still can't see anything wrong with your code. All I can think of is to not trust even the debugger, and actually perform a printout immediately before the 'setText' line, printing something like System.out.println("number is:"+output + ", label is:"+  lblFiles)...

Comment: I've done some research and the only thing I can think of is that the issue lies within data conversion between my database server and java application. SQLs Count() function may be returning a data type that is not proper to Java (possibly type BigInt or BigNumber). Would you have any knowledge about this?

Comment: Sorry, it never happened to me :(  But perhaps you could use getObject instead of getInt, namely  "Object x=rs.getObject(1)"  and see what you get: is it null? If not, what's x.getClass() ?

Comment: I just found out what was causing the issue. . You were indeed right when you first suspected it was the label somehow being declared null. I had a line that I completely missed when I quickly glanced through my code the first time upon reading your comment and quickly assumed I didn't make such a simple mistake.. but I did. Cheers!